# How to Build PDFium.dll with Gn and Ninja? (Preferably in one pdfium.dll)

Tags: c++, pdfium

I am trying to build PDFium as a dynamic library (Preferably in one pdfium.dll), but I couldn't figure out what Gn arguments are needed for that. I get some of the needed Dlls but pdfiume.dll is nowhere to be found.
I also get no build errors to troubleshoot.

on Windows 10 , used Gn and Ninja,  Want to implement with mvs 2019

Used Gn arguments:

```cpp
    is_component_build = true
    is_debug = false
    pdf_enable_v8 = false
    pdf_enable_xfa = false
    pdf_is_standalone = true
```

dlls that got generated by the build:

```cpp
    libpng.dll 
    zlib.dll 
    absl.dll 
    icuuc.dll
    partition_alloc.dll 
    libc++.dll
```

I'd really appreciate if someone could point to some hints Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try add this item in your gn file

clang_use_chrome_plugins = false

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately it generated the same dlls and pdfium.dll is still not generated.

Comment: I suggest that ,you can delete all project ,and reinstall and build it